# how to disable createuser button in createuserwizard after one click

Tags: asp.net

i am in a condition i want to disable create_user button of createuserwizard after one click to avoid duplicate records... actually i have updated the username in created_user event.. so now there is a possibility to enter record twice if user presses button twice..

I am not getting any property of that button to disable.. even i m not able to edit that button in the edit template..

even i dont know the id of that button so that i can use javascript to disable the button.

So please guide me how to do this..

```
            <asp:WizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server" Title="2. Enter Sponsor Details">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">Sponsor ID:</td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="SponsorID" runat="server" MaxLength="50"
                                Width="200px" CssClass="signup_textbox" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">Position:</td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"
                                RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="200px">
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Left</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Right</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </asp:WizardStep>

            <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep3" runat="server" Title="4. Create Your Login Password">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left"></td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="signup_textbox" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server"
                                    ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="Required"
                                    SetFocusOnError="True" ForeColor="Red" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr>
                            <td align="left">Email:</td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" CssClass="signup_textbox" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server"
                                    ControlToValidate="Email" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr>
                            <td align="left">Password:</td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"
                                    CssClass="signup_textbox" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" runat="server"
                                    ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left">Confirm Password:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"
                                    CssClass="signup_textbox" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator13" runat="server"
                                    ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword"
                                    ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                                <asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordCompare" runat="server"
                                    ControlToCompare="Password" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword"
                                    Display="Dynamic"
                                    ErrorMessage="Password and Confirm Password must match." ForeColor="Red"></asp:CompareValidator>
                                &nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
            <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server" Title="5. Finish">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <table style="color: #333333; background-color: #64C4EE; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center"
                                style="color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #757D89; font-weight: bold;">Complete</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Your account has been successfully created.</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Button ID="ContinueButton" runat="server" BackColor="White"
                                    BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"
                                    CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Continue" Font-Names="Verdana"
                                    ForeColor="#990000" Text="Finish" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
        </WizardSteps>
        <NavigationButtonStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966"
            BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana"
            ForeColor="#990000" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" BorderColor="#FFFBD6" BorderStyle="Solid"
            BorderWidth="2px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="0.9em" ForeColor="#333333"
            HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <CreateUserButtonStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966"
            BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana"
            ForeColor="#990000" CssClass="create_user_button" />
        <ContinueButtonStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966"
            BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana"
            ForeColor="#990000" />
        <SideBarStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Size="0.9em" VerticalAlign="Top" />
        <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SideBarButtonStyle ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

Comment: can you post your code please?

Comment: question is updated with the designer code...

Comment: does the button have a click event? if so can I see it?

Comment: no.. there is createduser event.. which trigger after the user is created